# Duplicate class error trying to build Android with Docusign dependency

Tags: android, docusignapi

I'm trying to implement the new [Docusign mobile Android SDK](https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk). but the Android build failed with Duplicate class error, even after adding the configuration section to exclude some groups and modules as the README.md instructions.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', module: 'retrofit'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', module: 'converter-gson'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.docusign', module: 'androidsdk-swagger'
}
```

Here it is part of log error:

```
... Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-22.0-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and gson-2.8.2.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and gson-2.8.2.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldAttributes found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and gson-2.8.2.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and gson-2.8.2.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$1 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and gson-2.8.2.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$2 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and gson-2.8.2.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$3 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and gson-2.8.2.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Address found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Authenticator found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Authenticator$1 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache$1 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache$2 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache$CacheRequestImpl found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache$CacheRequestImpl$1 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache$CacheResponseBody found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache$CacheResponseBody$1 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okhttp3.Cache$Entry found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout$1 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout$2 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.Base64 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer$1 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer$2 found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.BufferedSink found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.BufferedSource found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.ByteString found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.DeflaterSink found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingSink found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingSource found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingTimeout found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.GzipSink found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.GzipSource found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.HashingSink found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class okio.HashingSource found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and okio-1.15.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.IMarkerFactory found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.Logger found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.MDC found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.Marker found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.MarkerFactory found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMDCAdapter found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarker found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarkerFactory found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.FormattingTuple found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.MarkerIgnoringBase found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPMDCAdapter found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.NamedLoggerBase found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLogger found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLoggerFactory found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.helpers.Util found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.spi.MDCAdapter found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class org.slf4j.spi.MarkerFactoryBinder found in modules androidsdk-swagger-codegen-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallEnqueueObservable found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallEnqueueObservable$CallCallback found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable$CallDisposable found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.Result found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.ResultObservable found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.ResultObservable$ResultObserver found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapter found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)
Duplicate class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.package-info found in modules adapter-rxjava2-2.3.0.jar (com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0) and adapter-rxjava2-2.6.0.jar (com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0)...
```

I also tried to exclude every Duplicate class on error and it build successfully, but when I run the app crashes.

here it is build.gradle dependencies and configurations sections:

```
dependencies {
    //Android Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$jUnitVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:$androidTestCoreVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoInlineVersion"
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlinVersion"

    //Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:$coroutinesVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitGsonVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitRxJavaVersion"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'

    //OKHttp
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion"

    //Kotlin Injection
    implementation "org.koin:koin-java:$koinVersion"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koinVersion"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$koinVersion"
    testImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koinVersion"

    //RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"

    //Robolectric
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectricVersion"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:$robolectricVersion"

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.4'

    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8'
    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') {
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'net.authorize:accept-sdk-android:1.0.2'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.9.10'
    implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.21.2'
    implementation 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-fcm:9.7.1'
    implementation 'com.launchdarkly:launchdarkly-android-client:2.5.4'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:6.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'android-beacon-library'
    }

    implementation "com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:$appsFlyerVersion"
    implementation "com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:$installReferrerVersion"
    implementation 'com.docusign:androidsdk:1.0.0'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    all*.exclude group: "com.docusign", module: "androidsdk-swagger"
    all*.exclude group: "com.squareup.retrofit2", module: "retrofit"
    all*.exclude group: "com.squareup.retrofit2", module: "converter-gson"
    all*.exclude group: "com.squareup.retrofit2", module: "adapter-rxjava2"
    all*.exclude group: "com.google", module: "androidsdk-swagger"
    all*.exclude group: "com.google.code.gson", module: "gson"
    all*.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-api"
    all*.exclude group: "com.squareup.okio", module: "okio"
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
```

And I also have on `gradle.properties` this:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this issue in DocuSign android sdk version 1.0.1 which will be available soon. In that release, we don't need to exclude any configurations.

In the meanwhile can you provide the crash log if available.
Can you try removing the following from your configuration:

```
all*.exclude group: "com.google", module: "androidsdk-swagger"
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, after removing `all*.exclude group: "com.google", module: "androidsdk-swagger"` it is still crashing.
here is part of the log:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method keySet()Ljava/util/Set; in class Lcom/google/gson/JsonObject; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.gson.JsonObject' appears in /data/app/com.auction.resi.buyer.internal-4JKKcju-V1hzWN2WjokBdA==/base.apk:classes2.dex)
        at com.launchdarkly.android.LDClient.sendSummaryEvent(LDClient.java:696)
        at com.launchdarkly.android.LDClient.sendFlagRequestEvent(LDClient.java:656)`

Comment: Hi Alexandra, Can you try including the following in dependencies:              ```implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5' ```                                                    If it does not work, please wait for DocuSign android SDK version 1.0.1 and that should fix the issue.

Comment: Still not working, the same error. I will wait next version.

Comment: Hi Alexandra, we released DocuSign Android SDK 1.0.2 which should fix the issue. Please try with this latest release.

Comment: I had to add `all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'` to **configurations** ... but it is working now. Thanks!